# UITablewView Collapse Animation Speed

Tags: swift, uitableview

Following sections move up too fast and overlaps collapsing section.

Followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

        }else{
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

        }
    }
}
```

[image: initial]
[image: expanded]
[image: collapsing1]
[image: overlappede]

Answer (score 0):

You can always embed a table view update inside an animation block, thus controlling its duration. For example:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: durationInSeconds) {
  tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
}
```

Comment: it slows the animation but does not solve the overlap issue. my section and row view have different heights i think it behaves like they were same...